# Why is the Summon Perfect Warlord spell not more popular?

Tags: erfworld

In the web comic *Erfworld*, the spell “Summon Perfect Warlord” summons the perfect warlord, who may not be perfect by the standards of Erfworlders, but possesses the skills needed to accomplish whatever they were summoned for (along with, it seems, an associated Fate). The spell isn’t unknown to the denizens of the Magic Kingdom, since it was cast at least twice by different casters, so it’s probably known that it has been successful before: Judy Gale, for example, successfully performed the task for which she was summoned, croaking the Overladies of Easteros and Westeregg.

Even taking this into account, the cost of the spell is 500,000 Shmuckers, which might deter the average side from employing it in spite of its usefulness.

However, the spell also brings magical items with it. Parson’s calculator watch, for example, could be put in a bracer, creating a Mathamancy item whose value was calculated at 500,000 Shmuckers (the price of the SPW spell). He also came with the Sword of Ruthlessness, which might also have been a very valuable item, and the 3D glasses (which would be of limited value to any Erfworld unit). Judy Gale came with her own items, which were presumably similarly valuable.

Despite all these benefits, we’ve only seen it used twice: once in the  main comic, and once by a rather ancient side.

**Given that the spell more than pays for itself by bringing valuable magical items, not to mention a valuable warlord, why is it not more popular?**

Comment: I love this question, it's a pity that I discovered this web comic too late

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - If I recall correctly, the author's son had sex with a minor and then committed suicide, after which the author defended him online, then shut everything down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, talking about money kinda misses the point here, because the *spell is priceless*. Casters in Magic Kingdom put as high price as they could, because they knew Stanley would pay, but still it was like giving for free. They did it for their own purposes - it was wide conspiration, between Predictamancers, Eyemancers and Hippies.

The spell is maybe most powerful thing in whole Erfworld, like giving a small nuclear arsenal, but arguably even better. Nukes aren't usually for sale, so it was very unusual for casters to give away their most potent weapon. Also whole thing was more or less *secret*. Stanley had no idea something like this is possible, it was casters idea to "sell" this, or rather put the warlord as their pawn, where they saw him fit.

First known Perfect Warlord was Judy Gale, summoned for Charlie. Not even Arkentools saved his enemies from her, so she could be considered more powerful "weapon". Later Charlie has gone to great lengths to keep this secret, because only Perfect Warlord could stand to his power. Jack told Parson about it only after he died and was raised from dead (croaked and decrypted).

Summarizing, it is too powerful to be common, and war made by Parson is supposed to "end war itself" according to Janis. It's hard to imagine what would happen, if there were many such warlords on Erf.

Comment: Indeed, it's heavily implied that a) Charlie was *involved* in the crafting of the first Summon Perfect Warlord spell (and it was definitely crafted as well as cast, because only the GMTTA know of ways to get more than two disciplines into a caster-link and SPW was explicitly stated to have more components than that; current working hypothesis involves Carny-links to add more components to a precrafted scroll), b) Charlie learned how bad an idea this was by way of Judy, and c) the GMTTA have gone to some lengths to ensure they're the only others who know how to make such a spell.

Answer (score 1):

Warlords are known more for their decision making skills rather than their battle field ones. Strategic and tactical thinking over the raw martial prowess of a Dwagon, Shockamancer, or other truly high value unit in a side's battle line.

A good level 5 warlord and a poor level 5 warlord offer the same bonuses, but the good one has more intelligence to put against issues that confront him, whether raw intelligence, applicable knowledge about the enemies, or terrain knowledge derived from specials.

And the thing is, most bad leaders will still think their decision making is good, and therefore they don't need someone costing half a million Smuckers to tell them their decisions are good, units they pop for free already do that.

Answer (score 0):

There's also another factor as to why it's not more prevalent: it's very expensive.

During the course of the books we kind of lose sight of what an average side has at its disposal. Gobwin Knob is by all accounts a rather wealthy side to begin with, having all the gems from the mountain to supplement their natural shmucker uptake from cities and war.

From book 4, page 7, we know that Charlie has estimated the average side to have a treasury of 360,000 shmuckers. Gobwin Knob pre-Parson was still considered wealthy and had enough to buy the spell and support package (500,000 total 350,000 without support), but would have been broke, although it's not ever stated explicitly emptying the treasury could have potentially put GK in the unfortunate position of needing to harvest or disband units to maintain itself. However by not getting the "full spell" they still spent more money than most sides have at any given time.